# Why doesn't $("div[id*='\\|']") work in IE8 or IE9?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

Has anyone ever had the experience where IE8 and IE9 won't work with a jQuery selector where a special character is escaped?

This is the div I want to find:

```
<div id="hello|12345"></div>
```

And this is the jQuery selector I'm using to find it: `$("div[id*='\\|']")`

The result is that it doesn't get found, and I have no idea why. It's such a simple selector, and according to http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/, using `\\` is the proper way to escape the `|`. This of course works fine in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: You don't have to escape the `|` there. Try it without the ``\\``.

Comment: `|` is not a standard character in the id: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name. Any reason to have ids like that?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ does say that `|` is a special character though.

Comment: It worked for me in IE8 using this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FishBasketGordo/yrFPu/. What's your DOCTYPE?

Comment: @Hi there: It is not when inside attribute quotes.

Comment: Thanks BoltClock and Felix Kling; it did seem to be that the escaping was unnecessary. Removing the slashes made it work everywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two backslashes were actually unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me in IE 9 as long as I am using a jQuery version after 1.3.2:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZXPyW/

Are you using an old version?  If so, can you upgrade?

Answer (score 1):

`jQuery` uses this regex to parse the value part of an [attr=value] condition. So you cannot use it in id. Anyways it is not be used in the id as per the standard.

`(['"]*)(.*?)\3|)\s*\]`